# How to setup video meta data for TV Show grouping on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, itunes, metadata

What meta data on the video files do you need to setup in iTunes to have the videos group for TV Shows.  For example I have:

1. SomeShow Episode 1 Season 1
2. SomeShow Episode 2 Season 1
3. SomeShow Episode 3 Season 1
4. SomeShow Episode 4 Season 1

And the don't group.  They just show up as individual files on the iPhone and iTunes.

I have the following fields set for all episodes:

- **Video Tab**
- Show
- Episode
- Season
- **Info Tab**
- Name (filename minus the extension)
- **Sorting Tab**
- Name (filename minus the extension)
- Show (same as video tab)

**All other fields are blank.**

Is there something I need to remove or add to the meta data for this functionality to work?

**Edit:** I have tried updating the Sorting Tab and setting the Name Sort field to all the same to see if that would group them since the names are all diff due to the extra info included but that did nothing except make the sorting seem random now and still no grouping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the options tab, set "Media Kind" to "TV Show."

[image]

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that.  I have found a bunch of threads regarding this too and they all pointed to meta data.  Thanks!